# Looking for detailed comparisons between photonic vs other quantum hardware

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, continuous-variable

I’m looking for resources or literature that compares photonic devices and other quantum computing hardware using some performance metric. In other words, I am looking for grounds that compare the performance of a continuous variable algorithm (e.g. Grover’s search) implemented on photonic hardware vs the implementation of the same on superconducting qubits or trapped-ion qubits.

In case there’s no available literature, is there some performance metric to compare the implementations on a continuous variable and discrete variable simultaneously?